# Justifying text using DrawString in C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm drawing text on a `System.Drawing.Graphics` object. I'm using the `DrawString` method, with the text string, a `Font`, a `Brush`, a bounding `RectangleF`, and a `StringFormat` as arguments.

Looking into `StringFormat`, I've found that I can set it's `Alignment` property to `Near`, `Center` or `Far`. However I haven't found a way to set it to Justified. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I FOUND IT :)

http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/fully-justify-a-line-of-text-in-c/

in brief - you can justify text in each separate line when you know the given width of the entire paragraph:

```
float extra_space = rect.Width - total_width; // where total_width is the sum of all measured width for each word
int num_spaces = words.Length - 1; // where words is the array of all words in a line
if (words.Length > 1) extra_space /= num_spaces; // now extra_space has width (in px) for each space between words
```

the rest is pretty intuitive:

```
float x = rect.Left;
float y = rect.Top;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    gr.DrawString(words[i], font, brush, x, y);

    x += word_width[i] + extra_space; // move right to draw the next word.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do it.  Some work-arounds are mentioned on this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winforms/thread/aebc7ac3-4732-4175-a95e-623fda65140e

They suggest using an overridden `RichTextBox`, overriding the `SelectionAlignment` property (see [this page for how](http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/182.aspx)) and setting it to `Justify`.

The guts of the override revolve around this pInvoke call:

```
PARAFORMAT fmt = new PARAFORMAT();
fmt.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(fmt);
fmt.dwMask = PFM_ALIGNMENT;
fmt.wAlignment = (short)value;

SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), // "this" is the RichTextBox
    EM_SETPARAFORMAT,
    SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);
```

Not sure how well this can be integrated into your existing model (since I assume you're drawing more than text), but it might be your only option.