# How to align text in 80mm paper with vb.net

Tags: vertical-alignment, vb.net-2010, thermal-printer, leftalign

I wanted to aligned text on an 80mm paper from an Epson thermal printer.
I tried all I could by setting the margin from the device page on the PC it did not work. It prints but to the right and part of the text did not appear on the paper.
Please what can I do to solve this.

Comment: Instead of changing the printer's margin settings, it's a good idea to center it in the page when you create your document data. Then, because the size of the document exceeds the print area of the printer due to changing the margin setting, the rightmost part may not be printed.

Comment: Please do you have any code to do that using VB.net

Comment: For example, in C#, there is such an article. [Center text for receipt printing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30425393/9014308) Or, there is no approval, but also this article. [StringAlignment.Justify in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26923231/9014308)