# Justifying a string manually for DrawString() method in c#

Tags: c#, string, system.drawing, justify

I have implemented a fairly rudimentary 'Justify' method for drawing a string, however I would like to optimize it so the spacing is a bit more dispersed.

What I have so far, is this :

```
string lastword = line.Split(' ').Last();
string lineNoLastWord = line.Substring(0,line.LastIndexOf(" ")).Trim();;
g.DrawString( lineNoLastWord, Font, brush, textBounds, sf );
g.DrawString( lastword, Font, brush, textBounds, ConvertAlignment( System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right ) );
```

`ConvertAlignment` is a custom method as follows :

```
private StringFormat ConvertAlignment(System.Windows.TextAlignment align) {
    StringFormat s = new StringFormat();
    switch ( align ) {
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left:
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Justify:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Near;
            break;
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Far;
            break;
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Center;
            break;
    }
    s.Alignment = s.LineAlignment;
    return s;
}
```

The result is close, but needs some adjusting of the spaces in the string `lineNoLastWord`.

A bit more background behind the code.  `line` is the result of a method which is responsible for detecting if the string goes out of bounds (width), and breaking it into lines and words, breaking and measuring as it goes to ensure the full line remains within the width of the area to be drawn on. The method implements other properties in a much larger class, but here is the gist of it :

```
internal LineBreaker breakIntoLines( string s, int maxLineWidth ) {
    List<string> sResults = new List<string>();

    int stringHeight;
    int lineHeight;
    int maxWidthPixels = maxLineWidth;

    string[] lines = s.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( Pages[CurrentPage - 1] ) ) {
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        if ( maxLineWidth<=0||maxLineWidth>( Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width-X ) ) {
            maxWidthPixels=Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width-X;
        }
        lineHeight = (Int32)( g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height*(float)( (float)LineSpacing/(float)100 ) );
        stringHeight = (Int32)g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height;
        foreach ( string line in lines ) {
            string[] words=line.Split( new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None );
            sResults.Add( "" );
            for ( int i=0; i<words.Length; i++ ) {
                if ( sResults[sResults.Count-1].Length==0 ) {
                    sResults[sResults.Count-1]=words[i];
                } else {
                    if ( g.MeasureString( sResults[sResults.Count-1]+" "+words[i], Font ).Width<maxWidthPixels ) {
                        sResults[sResults.Count-1]+=" "+words[i];
                    } else {
                        sResults.Add( words[i] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new LineBreaker() {
        LineHeight = lineHeight,
        StringHeight = stringHeight,
        MaxWidthPixels = maxWidthPixels,
        Lines = sResults
    };
}

internal class LineBreaker {
    public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
    public int MaxWidthPixels { get; set; }
    public int StringHeight { get; set; }
    public int LineHeight { get; set; }

    public LineBreaker() {
        Lines = new List<string>();
        MaxWidthPixels = 0;
        StringHeight = 0;
        LineHeight = 0;
    }

    public LineBreaker( List<string> lines, int maxWidthPixels, int stringHeight, int lineHeight ) {
        Lines = lines;
        MaxWidthPixels = maxWidthPixels;
        LineHeight = lineHeight;
        StringHeight = stringHeight;
    }
}
```

The following image demonstrates the problem that this is causing :

[image: demonstration]

I have also seen [this stackoverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494131/justifying-text-using-drawstring-in-c-sharp), and found that it is also an inefficient way to space due to the unknown size of the string and the unknown width of the document will result in the string being too long if too many words, or too short with nothing right justified. Full justification means the text lines up on both the left and right side, and typically, the content inside is evenly spaced apart as much as possible. This is how I would like to implement it.

**The solution**, is likely a calculation on the `lastWord` and `lineNoLastWord` strings with some measurements to ensure viability of the output in that no two words in the string will run or bunch together, and there will be no padding on the right side, however left may still contain an indent or tab. Another part to consider, is if the string is shorter than a certain threshold, then no justification should be applied.

**UPDATE**

I have the following concept, which should work, just need to get the word from the specified index and insert the proper space :

```
int lastwordwidth = (Int32)g.MeasureString(" " + lastword, Font).Width;
int extraspace=lines.MaxWidthPixels-(Int32)( g.MeasureString( " "+lineNoLastWord, Font ).Width+lastwordwidth );
int totalspacesneeded = (Int32)Math.Floor((decimal)(extraspace / lines.SpaceWidth));
int spacecount = lineNoLastWord.Count(x => x == ' ');
int currentwordspace = 0;

for ( int i=0; i<spacecount; i++ ) {
    if ( currentwordspace>spacecount ) { currentwordspace = 0; }
    // insert spaces where spaces already exist between each word
    // use currentwordspace to determine which word to replace with a word and another space

    if ( currentwordspace==0 ) {
        // insert space after word
    } else {
        // insert space before word
    }

    currentwordspace++;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you see [this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/fully-justify-a-line-of-text-in-c/)? If calculates a float to know how far to move after __each__ word so it spreads the words __evenly__ over the line..

Comment: Yes, i saw that I suppose I could selectively insert spaces which would be faster causing fewer graphics calls.

Comment: Well you can or better you can use n-spaces but you will need to know their width rather precisely, which is not as simple as it sounds, given that most measurestring calls will not be as exact as one would hope for.. But do not worry about performance before you actually have a problem.. (See ['premature optimization'](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) ;-)

Comment: I am attempting this using the distance from the edge minus the length of the string. Taking that result and flooring the divisor of the width of a space. Next, will count the spaces and then, i dunno ...  some sort of insert space routine until the floor() result has been met.  It should be precise enough, and spread the spaces out among the first or last few words as necessary.  I have this setup as part of an async print to pdf routine (see my other articles, have made quite significant progress since i posted the solution)

Comment: @SanuelJackson, I'm unclear exactly what you want to achieve.  Do you _want_ a single gap before the last word, or gaps after each word?  Why not just use the system justification?  As an aside: are you aware that MeasureString tends to be inaccurate for detailed manipulation of text fragments or caret positioning - see the [remarks in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You mention PDF output;  is the final result drawing into a .Net Graphics, or are you measuring in order to inject text into a PDF writer library?

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse - class is custom which uses the microsoft pdf printer.  custom `newpage` allows for drawing all graphics on pages without calling print first (went over this on the other unrelated posts).  Right now, I am just stuck on `(Int32)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(extraspace / lines.SpaceWidth))` is always returning only `1` where `extraspace` is 49, and `lines.SpaceWidth` is 31.  Also, i havn't had any drawing/positional issues with measurestring since i take care to ensure dpi/etc is matching.

Comment: Fixed last problem. `int totalspacesneeded=(Int32)Math.Ceiling( (decimal)extraspace/(decimal)lines.SpaceWidth );` is what it should be

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this which works quite nicely. Following is my `DrawString` method which is text-alignment aware, and will break and add new 'Pages' as required. `Pages`, is a `List<Image>` object, and the `NewPage()` method is responsible for adding a new image to this list.

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a new string to the current page
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The string to print</param>
/// <param name="align">Optional alignment of the string</param>
public void DrawString(string text, System.Windows.TextAlignment align = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left, int MaxWidth = -1 ) {
    RectangleF textBounds;
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush( ForeColor );
    StringFormat sf = ConvertAlignment(align);
    LineBreaker lines = breakIntoLines(text, MaxWidth);

    int currentLine = 1;

    int originX = X;

    foreach ( string line in lines.Lines ) {
        // add string to document
        using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( Pages[CurrentPage - 1] ) ) {
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            textBounds=new RectangleF( X, Y, lines.MaxWidthPixels, lines.StringHeight );

            if ( align==System.Windows.TextAlignment.Justify ) {

                if ( currentLine<lines.Lines.Count ) {
                    string lastword=line.Split( ' ' ).Last();
                    if ( line.Contains( ' ' ) ) {
                        // routine to caclulate how much padding is needed and apply the extra spaces as evenly as possibly by looping
                        // through the words. it starts at the first word adding a space after if needed and then continues through the
                        // remaining words adding a space before them as needed and excludes the right most word which is printed as right
                        // align always.
                        string lineNoLastWord=line.Substring( 0, line.LastIndexOf( " " ) ).Trim();
                        List<string> words=lineNoLastWord.Split( ' ' ).ToList<string>();
                        int lastwordwidth=(Int32)g.MeasureString( " "+lastword, Font ).Width;
                        int extraspace=lines.MaxWidthPixels-(Int32)( g.MeasureString( " "+lineNoLastWord, Font ).Width+lastwordwidth );
                        int totalspacesneeded=(Int32)Math.Ceiling( (decimal)extraspace/(decimal)lines.SpaceWidth );
                        int spacecount=lineNoLastWord.Count( x => x==' ' );
                        int currentwordspace=0;

                        if ( words.Count>1 ) {
                            while ( totalspacesneeded>0 ) {
                                if ( currentwordspace>spacecount ) { currentwordspace=0; }
                                // insert spaces where spaces already exist between each word
                                // use currentwordspace to determine which word to replace with a word and another space
                                if ( currentwordspace==0 ) {
                                    // insert space after word
                                    words[currentwordspace]+=" ";
                                } else {
                                    // insert space before word
                                    words[currentwordspace]=" "+words[currentwordspace];
                                }
                                currentwordspace++;
                                totalspacesneeded--;
                                if ( totalspacesneeded==0 ) { break; }
                            }
                        }
                        lineNoLastWord=String.Join( " ", words );

                        g.DrawString( lineNoLastWord, Font, brush, textBounds, sf );
                        g.DrawString( lastword, Font, brush, textBounds, ConvertAlignment( System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right ) );
                    } else {
                        // when only 1 word, just draw it
                        g.DrawString( line, Font, brush, textBounds, ConvertAlignment( System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left ) );
                    }
                } else {
                    // just draw the last line
                    g.DrawString( line, Font, brush, textBounds, ConvertAlignment( System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left ) );
                }

            } else {
                g.DrawString( line, Font, brush, textBounds, sf );
            }
        }
        Y+=lines.LineHeight;
        if ( Y+lines.LineHeight>Pages[CurrentPage-1].Height ) {
            NewPage();
            if ( currentLine<lines.Lines.Count ) { X=originX; }
        }
        currentLine++;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Break a long string into multiple lines. Is also carriage return aware.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">the string</param>
/// <param name="maxLineWidth">the maximum width of the rectangle. if -1, will use the full width of the image</param>
/// <returns></returns>
internal LineBreaker breakIntoLines( string s, int maxLineWidth ) {
    List<string> sResults = new List<string>();

    int stringHeight;
    int lineHeight;
    int maxWidthPixels = maxLineWidth;
    int spaceWidth;

    string[] lines = s.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( Pages[CurrentPage - 1] ) ) {
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        if ( maxLineWidth<=0||maxLineWidth>( Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width-X ) ) {
            maxWidthPixels=Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width-X;
        }
        lineHeight = (Int32)( g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height*(float)( (float)LineSpacing/(float)100 ) );
        stringHeight = (Int32)g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height;
        spaceWidth=(Int32)g.MeasureString( " ", Font ).Width;
        foreach ( string line in lines ) {
            string[] words=line.Split( new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None );
            sResults.Add( "" );
            for ( int i=0; i<words.Length; i++ ) {
                if ( sResults[sResults.Count-1].Length==0 ) {
                    sResults[sResults.Count-1]=words[i];
                } else {
                    if ( g.MeasureString( sResults[sResults.Count-1]+" "+words[i], Font ).Width<maxWidthPixels ) {
                        sResults[sResults.Count-1]+=" "+words[i];
                    } else {
                        sResults.Add( words[i] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new LineBreaker() {
        LineHeight = lineHeight,
        StringHeight = stringHeight,
        MaxWidthPixels = maxWidthPixels,
        Lines = sResults,
        SpaceWidth = spaceWidth
    };
}

/// <summary>
/// Helper method to convert TextAlignment to StringFormat
/// </summary>
/// <param name="align">System.Windows.TextAlignment</param>
/// <returns>System.Drawing.StringFormat</returns>
private StringFormat ConvertAlignment(System.Windows.TextAlignment align) {
    StringFormat s = new StringFormat();
    switch ( align ) {
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left:
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Justify:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Near;
            break;
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Far;
            break;
        case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center:
            s.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Center;
            break;
    }
    s.Alignment = s.LineAlignment;
    return s;
}

/// <summary>
/// Class to hold the line data after broken up and measured using breakIntoLines()
/// </summary>
internal class LineBreaker {
    public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
    public int MaxWidthPixels { get; set; }
    public int StringHeight { get; set; }
    public int LineHeight { get; set; }

    public int SpaceWidth { get; set; }

    public LineBreaker() {
        Lines = new List<string>();
        MaxWidthPixels = 0;
        StringHeight = 0;
        LineHeight = 0;
        SpaceWidth = 0;
    }

    public LineBreaker( List<string> lines, int maxWidthPixels, int stringHeight, int lineHeight, int spaceWidth ) {
        Lines = lines;
        MaxWidthPixels = maxWidthPixels;
        LineHeight = lineHeight;
        StringHeight = stringHeight;
        SpaceWidth = spaceWidth;
    }
}
```

The above method combination supports :

- Left alignment
- Right alignment
- Center alignment
- Justify alignment - The last line sent with Justify, will just be printed left aligned as this is usually the end of a paragraph.
- All lines sent will check the constraints using the image, or a width specified that is within range between the current X position and the edge. Widths exceeding or in the negative range will be set to the distance between X and the right side of the image. Each line is within it's own bounding box.
- Lines are not clipped.
- Line wrapping is broken on word as required and on carriage returns ("\n" or "\r\n")

`LineSpacing` is just an integer where 100 means 100% of LineHeight.
`X` is an integer for getting/setting the `X` position.
`Y` is an integer for getting/setting the `Y` position.
`Font` is a getter/setter for a `System.Drawing.Font`